# Track visitors across different domains using Google Analytics even when they don't click between the sites

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

Apparently there are ways to track visitors across different domain using google analytics as described in documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite) and [here](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2015/06/16/cross-domain-tracking-google-tag-manager/).

It follows the principle where a visitor click on a link on `website1.com` and get redirects to `website2.com` with some additional path params which helps GA track if the visitor is same and GA maintain it's session.

I have been looking around a lot and couldn't find a solution on how can I track a visitor which comes on `website1.com` through ads and then leaves (And/Or open new tab) and immediately/later goes on to `website2.com` and make some purchase. I am not targeting to maintain session per user but at least I need to know if it's the same visitor which goes there and converts.

I definately have access to both sites and can put GA tags and javaScripts on both websites.

Comment: I was going to write an answer but I realized I would just be retyping documentation. In current versions of GA this is a bit easier and doesn't require parameters on links. I recommend Google Tag Manager if you can (see https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164469 ), but analytics.js can also do cross-domain tracking: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en  Reading both of those should give you a good sense. You need domain linking, referral exclusion, and possibly GA filters to tell you which site a pageview was on.

Comment: Thanks Reve, I'll test it out and let know here the result